# Why Sum $> 1/2$ in proving reciprocal of prime diverges

Tags: number-theory

In my number theory book it says that to show that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges, it’s enough to show that, for any $j$:
$$\frac{1}{p_{j+1}}+\frac{1}{p_{j+2}}+\frac{1}{p_{j+3}}+\cdots>\frac{1}{2}$$

Why is it enough to show that the above sum is greater than $1/2$?

Comment: Because if the sum did converge, then there's be a $j$ such that everything after the $j$th term sums to less than $1/2$. This is just from the definition of a convergent series.

Comment: @Nishant I still don't understand

Comment: There's nothing special about $\frac12$. Any positive (nonzero) number works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that if the sum converges, after a bunch of terms it is close to the final sum.  This seems to be the concept you are missing. As all the terms are positive, proving the tail exceeds $\frac 12$ or any other positive number proves that the sum is not close to any proposed limit.  In this case a slightly more formal proof might help.  To prove a sum converges to $L$, we need to prove that for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is an $N$ so that the sum of at least $N$ terms is within $\epsilon$ of $L$.  If the tail sum is always greater than $\frac 12$ and I give you $\epsilon = \frac 14$, you can't find an $N$ that works.

Answer (score 2):

If $\sum \frac{1}{p_i} = N$ converges, then by definition
\begin{align*}
\left|N - \sum_{i \leq n} \frac{1}{p_i}\right| = \sum_{i > n} \frac{1}{p_i} \to 0
\end{align*}
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I dont understnad how this leads to 1/2.

Comment: Well, if it's bounded from below by $\frac{1}{2}$, it can't tend to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Taking "any" to mean "every", the point would be that **no matter how large $j$ gets,** that sum remains bigger than $1/2$.  If the sum of the reciprocals converges, then after some finite number of terms, the partial sum is more than the total sum minus $0.001$.  Take $j$ bigger than that number of terms, and the tail of the series would then add up to less than $0.001$.  And similarly for all other small positive numbers.  But if the tail never gets less than $1/2$, then it can't get less than $0.001$ or any of those other tiny numbers.

To put it another way, if the series $\displaystyle\frac 1 {p_1}+\frac 1 {p_2}+ \frac 1 {p_3} + \cdots$ converges, then
$$
\frac 1 {p_j} + \frac 1 {p_{j+1}} + \frac 1 {p_{j+2}} + \cdots \to 0\text{ as }j\to\infty.
$$

Comment: What is the tail of the series mean?

Comment: The tail of the series $\displaystyle\frac 1 {p_1}+\frac 1 {p_2}+ \frac 1 {p_3} + \cdots$ is the expression $\displaystyle\frac 1 {p_j} + \frac 1 {p_{j+1}} + \frac 1 {p_{j+2}} + \cdots$, whose value depends on $j$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: and what does that result in when j goes to infinity

Comment: As $j$ approaches $\infty$, the sum of the tail of the series approaches $0$ if the series converges.

Comment: is that the same as limit

Comment: @Sandikae : It is a limit.  Whether it is the same as some other limit is another matter.